# Removing all whitespace characters except for " "

Tags: java, regex

I consider myself pretty good with Regular Expressions, but this one is appearing to be surprisingly tricky:  I want to trim **all** whitespace, **except** the space character: `' '`.

In Java, the RegEx I have tried is: `[\s-[ ]]`, but this one also strips out `' '`.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the particular string that I am attempting to strip spaces from:

```
project team                manage key
```

Note: it would be the characters between "team" and "manage".  They appear as a long space when editing this post but view as a single space in view mode.

Comment: You can replace all spaces with a character you know won't be present, remove all whitespaces and change the special character back to a space.

Comment: True (this trick actually already occurred to me) and I suspect it would work but would require three replacements instead of one.

Comment: So... uh... you would want your output string to read `project teammanage key`?

Comment: You'd better tell us what character it is. We see only a lot of spaces. It may be anything. Note that `\s` in Java doesn't cover all Unicode spaces, see my comment below and http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ

Comment: In the debugger: this character is showing as "32"

Comment: As a decimal value, 32 *is* a space (in Unicode and ASCII); as a hex value it's the character '2'.  So I think you are confused w/r/t what's between team and manage.

Comment: Ok, folks, I stand corrected.  There was some messed up application behavior masking the underlying issue.  Specifically, these **were** spaces, but for some reason they were displaying as one space in some instances and multiple spaces in others.  So yes: Issue resolved now.  Thanks folks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current Java definition of `\s` is for ASCII only, not for Unicode, Java’s native character set. Therefore its definition of `\S` is also wrong for Unicode.  However, this is [comparitively easily fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java/4731164#4731164).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using this regular expression:

```
[^\S ]+
```

It's a bit confusing to read because of the double negative. The regular expression `[\S ]` matches the characters you want to keep, i.e. either a space or anything that isn't a whitespace. The negated character class `[^\S ]` therefore must match all the characters you want to remove.

Comment: Good thought, but this didn't actually work.  This seems logically equivalent to my original attempt (which uses subtraction).  I'm beginning to think that I need to specify ranges and/or specific characters to strip, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I should note that if I do a replace all on "\s" it strips out all the whitespace but it also strips out ' ', which is too aggressive.

Comment: It must work.... and it does. Try `System.out.println("\t aaa \t\n".replaceAll("[^\\S ]", "").getBytes());`.

Comment: @Mark Byers  Yes, I used uppercase "S" and I am aware of the need for double-backslashes.   @maaartinus:  the whitespace I am trying to remove here are not tabs ... honestly I'm not sure what the exact whitespace chars are, but I **do** know that these are not tabs or new lines **and** "\\s" is able to strip them out.

Comment: @Ryan Delucchi: Can you print the string out to a file and then copy and paste it into your question so that we can see exactly what characters you are trying to remove?

Comment: `I'm not sure what the exact whitespace chars are` how about hex-dumping the string so you can find out what exactly they are (and tell us)?

Comment: Use e.g. `getBytes("utf-8")` and output them as numbers for finding out what it is.

Comment: @maaartinus:  I just did a getBytes("utf-8") and I get the value: 32

Comment: @ColinD:  I wonder if these spaces are being translated.  Because, whatever space-character I am dealing with "\\s" matches it but can't be distinguished from a regular space ... in RegEx at least.

Comment: @Ryan: Besides space, \s only matches character tab, line tab, form feed, line feed and carriage return.

Comment: All the answers here were useful, but I ended up using this one.

Answer (score 7):

Using a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
String text = ...
String stripped = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.and(CharMatcher.isNot(' '))
    .removeFrom(text);
```

If you actually just want that trimmed from the start and end of the string (like `String.trim()`) you'd use `trimFrom` rather than `removeFrom`.

Comment: The definition of whitespace here differs from the one used by \s. It is better (closer to Unicode standard).

Answer (score 3):

There's no subtraction of character classes in Java, otherwise you could use `[\s--[ ]]`, note the double dash. You can always simulate set subtraction using intersection with the complement, so

```
[\s&&[^ ]]
```

should work. It's no better than `[^\S ]+` from the first answer, but the principle is different and it's good to know both.

Comment: This isn't working either.  I'm rather surprised: as doing a match on "\s" seems to be removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
anyString.replace(/[\f\t\n\v\r]*/g, '');
```

It is just a collection of all possible white space characters excluding blank (so actually
\s without blanks). It includes tab, carriage return, new line, vertical tab and form feed characters.