# Cannot detect space more than one?

Tags: java, string

**UPDATE**

Seem like when I copy string from this question `"       AAAAAA"` and replace it. The program works correctly.

So I just do some test by changing back `"       AAAAAA"` to my previous error string.
then remove all the space and input it manually by typing and it works !?!?.

Here is my full code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://writer.dek-d.com/nattione/story/viewlongc.php?id=466201&chapter=966");

        is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException
        String result = convertStreamToString(is);
        createFictionFiles(result);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}

public static void createFictionFiles(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element title = doc.select("title").first();
    Element table = doc.select("#story_body").first();
    
    String showTitle = "";
    String showStory = "";
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        showTitle = new String(title.text());
        showStory = new String(table.text());
        //showStory = "       AAAAAA"; these spaces I copy it from log in eclipse. It is the spaces that come from web
        boolean find = showStory.contains("\\t");
        boolean find1 = showStory.contains("\\n");
        boolean find2 = showStory.contains("\\x0b");
        boolean find3 = showStory.contains("\\r");
        boolean find4 = showStory.contains("\\f");
        boolean find5 = showStory.contains(" ");
        boolean find6 = showStory.contains("  ");
        boolean find7 = showStory.matches("\\s");
        System.out.println("\\t = " + find);
        System.out.println("\\n = " + find1);
        System.out.println("\\x0b = " + find2);
        System.out.println("\\r = " + find3);
        System.out.println("\\f = " + find4);
        System.out.println(" = " + find5);
        System.out.println("  = " + find6);
        System.out.println("\\s = " + find7);

        File file = new File("D:/" + "test"
                + ".txt");
        
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(showStory);
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is, "TIS-620").useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

**OLD**

I have this String

```
showStory = "       AAAAAA";
```

these string is retrieve from web and parse it into String format by using [library](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

I want to seperate that with space more than 3 in will replace them with `"\n"`

I have these tests.

```
boolean find = showStory.contains("\\t");
boolean find1 = showStory.contains("\\n");
boolean find2 = showStory.contains("\\x0b");
boolean find3 = showStory.contains("\\r");
boolean find4 = showStory.contains("\\f");
boolean find5 = showStory.contains(" ");
boolean find6 = showStory.contains("  ");
boolean find7 = showStory.contains("\\s");
```

and the results are

```
\t = false
\n = false
\x0b = false
\r = false
\f = false
 = true
  = false
\s = false
```

I don't know why more than one space give me false even though in my String have 8 spaces.
I also change the method from `contains` to `matches` but all results are false.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code [returns true when I run it on ideone](http://ideone.com/iEs7Z7). What am I missing?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I wrote a small program with exactly the same inputs, and received `true` for all spaces up to length 8.

Comment: It must be that when you receive it from the web it only returns one ' ' I guess

Comment: 1. `.contains` does not take a regular expression. 2. `.matches` tries to match the whole string, not a partial match.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4731055/422353

Comment: I following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731164/1289480 and when I call matches by using whitespace_charclass. The result is false.

Answer (score 3):

please check again ... there is no way it wont recognize the 2 spaces in find6

```
 String showStory = "       AAAAAA";

 boolean find = showStory.contains("\\t");
 boolean find1 = showStory.contains("\\n");
 boolean find2 = showStory.contains("\\x0b");
 boolean find3 = showStory.contains("\\r");
 boolean find4 = showStory.contains("\\f");
 boolean find5 = showStory.contains(" ");
 boolean find6 = showStory.contains("  ");
 boolean find7 = showStory.contains("\\s");

 System.out.println("find ="+find);
 System.out.println("find1 ="+find1);
 System.out.println("find2 ="+find2);
 System.out.println("find3 ="+find3);
 System.out.println("find4 ="+find4);
 System.out.println("find5 ="+find5);
 System.out.println("find6 ="+find6);
 System.out.println("find7 ="+find7);


  }//end of main
```

and this is the print :

```
find =false
find1 =false
find2 =false
find3 =false
find4 =false
find5 =true
find6 =true
find7 =false
```

Comment: Um, when I copy your string from this web it works correctly. Please see my update.