# Whitespace matching regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am currently trying to make use of the java string function `someString.replaceAll()` to find commonly used words (and, the, by, of, etc) and replace them with `" "`. Based on the answers to the question at [Whitespace Matching Regex - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java), I produced this function call:

```
data.replaceAll("(?i)\\sthe\\s", " ")
```

However, it isnt working and I'm really not sure why. Nothing about it looks wrong based on what I've found.  Please help me!

Comment: It isn't working -  means? What output are you getting after that replace?

Comment: Meaning that it isn't replacing any of the words that I place in the regex with " ".  It led me to assume that my regex wasnt matching the word, but I dont know why it isnt, since it looks right to me

Comment: commonly words without a pattern just use `replace` instead of replaceAll

Comment: Can you post complete code? I tried the following and it seems to replace 'The' string with space. For input 'me The rt', the code below prints 'me rt'.
        String data = "me The rt";
        String result = data.replaceAll("(?i)\\sthe\\s", " "); 
        System.out.println(result);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable!

```
data = data.replaceAll("(?i)\\sthe\\s", " ");
```