# Convert spaces to underscores

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, whitespace

I am retrieving a player-list from a server and I am doing stuff with it (un-related to problem) later on. These un-related processes only work if  the username doesn't have spaces, but instead has the character `'_'` instead of `' '`. I am using this code to loop through each playername's character and then detect if its a `' '` and, if it is, replace it with a `'_'` but for some reason it doesn't get detected at all?

```
    char[] name;

    for(String playerName : chatlist) {
        name = playerName.toCharArray();

        for(int i =0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if(name[i] == ' ') {
                name[i] = '_';
            }
        }

        String nameS = new String(name);
        System.out.println(playerName + " -> " + nameS);
    }
```

An example of a username and output is the following:

`Testuser 1` would output `Testuser_1`

`ExampleUser One` would output `ExampleUser_One`

Comment: Is this meant to be Java or C#? `Console.WriteLine` looks much more like C# than Java...

Comment: (And having copied your code, it works for me. Please show a short but complete program with it *not* working.)

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet I put that in there last minute :P Fixed now it is supposed to be System.out.println

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual ASCII space (hex `0x20`)? There are multiple other whitespace characters. http://decodeunicode.org/en/u+0020

Comment: Well there's still the issue that it already works if the value really contains a space...

Answer (score 8):

Use `replaceAll("\\s+", "_")`. It's the better way of doing it. 
Else you will be replacing each space with an "_" (is this what you want?)

Comment: Yes I want to replace all spaces with the character '_'

Comment: @DuncanPalmer - Each space.. you mean abc(3 spaces)def should show abc___def ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`playerName.replace(' ', '_')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Comment: Why would this work any better? The OP's code works for me.

Comment: @Duncan - smaller / simpler code :)

Comment: @WhoAmI This is not http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. That being said, the answer would be ok if it also addressed the underlying problem. Trouble is - there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: @Duncan - I agree. Yet, the answer shows another way of doing it.

Comment: It makes the programmer's intentions succinct and clear. "this is the player name with spaces converted to underscores", as opposed to 20 lines of code which, after someone reads through it and works out what it does, discovers it replaces spaces with underscores.

Comment: @StuartCaie I'm just pointing out that an answer should address the issue described in the problem. Maybe this would have been a good comment. Either way, I don't feel overly strongly (hence lack of down-vote).

Answer (score 2):

This code works as expected:

```
private static List<String> chatlist = Arrays.asList("Mr. Who", "Dr. Me");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String playerName : chatlist) {
        char[] name = playerName.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if (name[i] == ' ') name[i] = '_';
        }
        String nameS = new String(name);
        System.out.println(playerName + " -> " + nameS);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Mr. Who -> Mr._Who
Dr. Me -> Dr._Me
```

Maybe the space character you expect isn't a space at all? You may inspect the characters of the player names by printing out their codes like this `System.out.println((int) ' ')`. The space character code is `32`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop works for me. Are you sure `chatlist` isn't  null?

But as others have said, a simpler way would be `name.replace(' ', '_'). This is better because it makes your code shorter and more readable. Everyone, including you, knows exactly what you're trying to do in that *one* line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4731164/1434909) and use `String.replaceAll` instead of a manual char replacement.

Just for clarification - in this answer a complete set of all whitespace characters is matched, instead of just space.