# How to write optional word in Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write a java Regular expression that recognises the following patterns.
    `abc def the ghi` and `abc def ghi`

I tried this:

```
abc def (the)? ghi
```

But, it is not recognizing the second pattern.Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
abc def (the )?ghi

           ^^
```

Remove the extra `space`

Comment: Are java regex different in any sense from the normal regex. Bear my ignorance.I'm asking this becaue your soln worked here. http://www.regexr.com/ . but not when I'm writing for a java regex.So,this is what i did abc def (\sthe)?ghi. this only worked when the is not there.

Comment: @vks I wrote   abc def(\\sthe)?ghi  .still same result.didn't  I get it right?

Comment: @anil it should be `abc def(\\sthe)? ghi`

Comment: @vks It didn't .To be specific,I'm using stanford regexner for my project.As a part of that, I wrote this regular expression.The Regex written above is working fine when the "the" part is not there.But when it is,pattern is not being recognised.Somewhere in other thread,there is a discussion that java treats spaces in a different way,I'll post the link here.Please help me if you can.Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java

Comment: @anil instead of `\\s` you can try ` ` literal space

Answer (score 5):

Spaces are also valid characters in regex, so

```
abc def (the)? ghi
       ^      ^ --- spaces
```

can match only

```
abc def the ghi
       ^   ^---spaces
```

or when we remove `the` word

```
abc def  ghi
       ^^---spaces
```

You need something like `abc def( the)? ghi` to also make one of these spaces optional.

Answer (score 0):

Your example worked perfectly well for me in Python

```
    x = "def(the)?"
    s = "abc def the ghi"
    res = re.search(x, s)
```

Returns: res -> record

```
    s = "abc def ghi"
    res = re.search(x, s)
```

Returns: res -> record

```
    s = "abc Xef ghi"
    res = re.search(x, s)
```

Returns: res -> None