# Getting regex redirection to cater for optional text

Tags: regex, redirect

So, I have a series of regex redirections for some help topics.

Example:

```
(?i)\/msa/HelpOnline/source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm$
```

If the user had used the **search tab** in the old help system and clicked on the same link for the above topic the resulting link was:

```
/msa/helponline/index.html?page=source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm
```

So, I have an option bit of URL that might be present:

```
/msa/helponline/[index.html?page=]source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm
```

Is it possible with regex to optionally allow for that text so that with the same redirection we can find:

```
/msa/helponline/source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm
/msa/helponline/index.html?page=source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm
```

I am using the Wordpress Redirection plugin and the redirections are being stored with Wordpress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write optional word in Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566087/how-to-write-optional-word-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
(?i)\/msa/HelpOnline/(index.html\?page=)?source/helpoptionsemailgoogle.htm$
```