# Generating pattern that adds + sign between spaces as one string for each line

Tags: java, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

I am using a scanner to read a file which is structured as follows:

```
 ali nader sepahi
 simon nadel
 rahim nadeem merse
 shahid nadeem
```

Each line has a multiple strings which represented the full name of the person. How to add "+" in between spaces for each name, so I will be having something like this **"ali+nader+sepahi"** printed into one String.

```
public class dataScanner
{   
    public dataScanner() throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));

     while(file.hasNext())
     {
         String s = file.next().trim();
          System.out.println(s+"+");
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably try taking a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java

Comment: So your String of course is generated when it reads from the file using .next(), then instead of just printing it out and appending a "+" at the end, you can use s.replace(" ","+")

Comment: I did not know about the replace method that can be used to append the plus sign. Very Useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Scanner.nextLine` to read the whole line, then [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) the spaces with `+`

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of need, a `Scanner` is not really suitable, you should use a `BufferedReader` and [String.replace(char, char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) as next:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("info.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line.replace(' ', '+'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used your sample of code which has worked perfectly.