# Regex match a whitespace table

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match rows of a table. There are no symbols which signal where one cell starts or ends but whitespace. Strings of characters with < 3 whitespace in between should be seen as cells.

An example row:

```
"           here is a $$ cell               here  another         cells I dont care about........."
```

This is my naive and invalid attempt in which I just want 2 cells:

```
\\s{5,}([^\\s{2,}]+)\\s{5,}([^\\s{2,}]+)\\s{5,}.*
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whitespace Matching Regex - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java)

Comment: What about the leading/trailing spaces? Do you expect any empty cells? See [this demo, BTW](https://ideone.com/Y6HYFl).

Comment: No I don't expect any empty cells. I essentially look for the first n clusters of characters.

Comment: So, is the `["here is a $$ cell", "here  another", "cells I dont care about........."]` expected output then?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that was unclear. I simply need 2 matches in this case though. So I guess I'd just take the first two list elements.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/c1SJiO/1)?

Comment: Ok, I posted the answer showing how to grab the first 2 cell values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may trim the input first, and then split with 3 or more whitespaces, then check if you got the first 2 cell values and use them :

```
String s = "           here is a $$ cell               here  another         cells I dont care about.........";
String[] res = s.trim().split("\\s{3,}");
if (res.length > 1) {
    System.out.println(res[0]); // Item 1
    System.out.println(res[1]); // Item 2, the rest is unimportant
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Y6HYFl)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick hopefully:

```
 (?<=\s{3,}|^\s?\s?)\w[\w\W]*?(?=\s{3,}|\s?\s?$)
```

With Java formatting it is:

```
"(?<=\\s{3,}|^\\s?\\s?)\\w[\\w\\W]*?(?=\\s{3,}|\\s?\\s?$)"
```

What it does is it tries to match a group of characters as short as possible that starts with a non white space character (so it doesn't match a single space).Then it checks behind if there are at least 3 white spaces or the line start and then checks if there are at least 3 white spaces or the line end after the match.

It only matches one cell so just repeat the expression to match multiple cells.

You can mess around with this here: http://fiddle.re/0tmcza