# white space matching regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have the following two patterns to match an html tag name with possible leading spaces. The first pattern where `[ ]*` is inside the named group `<doubletag>` doesn't work, but the second pattern where `[ ]*` is immediately following the tag symbol `"<"` works. I don't know why the first doesn't work.

```
 String s = "<      pre href = "dajflka" >ld fjalj09u293 ^% </pre>";
 Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("(<(?<doubletag>[ ]*[a-z]+)([ \\d\\s\\w\\W[^>]])*>)(.*)(</\\k<doubletag>[ ]*>)");
 Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile("(<[ ]*(?<doubletag>[a-z]+)([ \\d\\s\\w\\W[^>]])*>)(.*)(</\\k<doubletag>[ ]*>)");
 Matcher match = ptr.matcher(s);
 if(match.find()){
        System.out.println("Found");
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java

Comment: Parsing HTML with RegExp is not that precise, you should used something like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Titus I know. I just was solving a problem with regex in hackerrank. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the first pattern can find the leading white spaces. If you try the first group of the first pattern only:

```
String s = "<      pre href = \" dajflka \" >";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(?<doubletag>[ ]*[a-z]+)([ \\d\\s\\w\\W[^>]])*>");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);
if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found");
    System.out.println(match.group("doubletag"));
}
```

you will get `doubletag`:

```
"      pre"
```

The problem is, in  `</pre>`, it does not have the prefix whitespaces, so group `(</\k<doubletag>[ ]*>)` can not be found. That's why the first pattern can not match the whole string.

Comment: That do it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`\s` is the white space , if that is what you want , put `[\s]*`.

Comment: The problem isn't about the way [ ]* or \\s* doesn't matter. The problem is that the first pattern doesn't match the white space although I accounted for it in the group "<(?<doubletag>[ ]*...."  ,but when I use the try the second pattern where I move the [ ]* before the group as "<[ ]*(?<doubletag>...."  it works fine. To me, both looks similar. So, why the first doesn't work?